# jQuery ajax-- returning data to calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a simple generic ajax function that can be called by multiple functions in my script. I'm not sure how to get the data returned to the ajax function back to the caller.

```
// some function that needs ajax data
function myFunction(invoice) {
    // pass the invoice data to the ajax function
    var result = doAjaxRequest(invoice, 'invoice');
    console.dir(result); // this shows `undefined`
}

// build generic ajax request object
function doAjaxRequest(data, task) {
    var myurl = 'http://someurl';
    $.ajax({
        url: myurl + '?task=' + task,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            console.dir(data); // this shows good data as expected  
            return data; // this never gets back to the calling function
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to return the ajax data to the calling function?

Comment: No. The calling function has finished running before the AJAX call is even initiated. You could make it synchronous... but then it's not AJAX.

Comment: Couldn't he pass a (possibly anonymous) callback function to the `doAjaxRequest` function and then invoke it from the success closure?

Comment: @TheZ-- crap-- obvious now. Thanks for the help with a dumb question!

Comment: @KevinBoucher He could, but that wouldn't be passing it back to the calling function as a return. That would be a callback.

Comment: @Z: agreed, but it might be a solution to his overall issue.

Comment: @KevinBoucher True, but that kind of information belongs in an answer, not a comment :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous, so in order to get the data back you will need to pass a callback to your `doAjaxRequest` function. I've added a callback parameter to `doAjaxRequest` and instead of using the result of `doAjaxRequest` the code that handles the response is in the callback function.

```
// some function that needs ajax data
function myFunction(invoice) {
    // pass the invoice data to the ajax function
    doAjaxRequest(invoice, 'invoice', function (result) { 
        console.dir(result);
    });
}

// build generic ajax request object
function doAjaxRequest(data, task, callback) {
    var myurl = 'http://someurl';
    $.ajax({
        url: myurl + '?task=' + task,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            console.dir(data); // this shows good data as expected  
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i think help full to you this example

```
function testAjax() {
    var result="";
    $.ajax({
      url:"getvalue.php",
      async: false,  
      success:function(data) {
         result = data; 
      }
   });
   return result;
}

function fun2()
{

alert(testajax())

}
```

you notice one thing  async: false